# How do I link static library and dynamic library at the same time?

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I have written a makefile like the following:

```
COMPILER = g++
COMPILER_FLAGS = -c -g -O0 -Wall -w
EXEC=mhu9_mp3
LD = g++
LINKER = g++

mhu9_mp3 : mhu9_mp3.o teapot.o EasyBMP.o 
    $(LD) teapot.o mhu9_mp3.o EasyBMP.o -L./SOIL/lib -lSOIL -o mhu9_mp3 -L./usr/lib -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lGLEW 

teapot.o : teapot.cpp teapot.h
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) teapot.cpp

mhu9_mp3.o : mhu9_mp3.cpp teapot.h 
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) mhu9_mp3.cpp 

EasyBMP.o : EasyBMP_1.06/EasyBMP.cpp 
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) EasyBMP_1.06/EasyBMP.cpp

clean:
    -rm -f *.o mhu9_mp3
```

where `libSOIL.a` is a static library (I linked it by using `-L./SOIL/lib -lSOIL`) and `-lGL -lGLU -lglut -lGLEW` are dynamic libraries. I have linked them together at the same line. In my `.cpp` file I have a function call that calls a function defined in `SOIL.h`. However, when I compiled I got this error:

```
undefined reference to `SOIL_load_image'
```

I'm pretty sure I have included the header file `SOIL.h`, and also I have linked in the static library `libSOIL.a`. So what is the reason for this error? I try adding a `-static` flag before the `-lSOIL` but the linker wrongly assumes other dynamics libraries are static. Is there any better ways of linking static and dynamic libraries at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Counterpart of `-static` is `-Bdynamic`. So if you really have to, it could be something like

```
ld -o foo foo.o -static -lstaticlib -Bdynamic -ldynamiclib0 -ldynamiclib1
```

However, this makes sense only when both dynamic and static libraries are present. If only one exists, linker will chose one itself.

In your case, problem may be caused by wrong link order or by the fact that `SOIL_load_image` is indeed missing (verify it with `nm` or `objdump`).

Answer (score 0):

Put the list of dynamic libraries before the list of static libraries.

Example:

```
$(LD) -L<path> -l<dynamiclib1> -l<dynamiclib2> -static -l<staticlib1> -l<staticlib2>
```

Comment: I don't think the *-dynamic* option actually exists.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It is actually `-dy` or `-Bdynamic`. Too rarely used to be remembered :-(